# Cocoa - Adding a Navigation Controller to a subview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently working on a view based app for the iPad that has 3 seperate views on the main page. A custom menu up the top, a status list on the side, and a main view. The issue I am having with the main view is trying to add a navigation controller.

In AppPadViewController.h

```
@interface AppPadViewController.h : UIViewController {
    MainViewController *MainView;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet MainViewController *MainView;
```

And in AppPadViewController.m

```
@synthesize MainView;

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MainView.navigationItem.title = @"Home";
    UINavigationController *mainNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    self.MainView = [MainViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainNavController];
}
```

And in the nib I have added the view where I would like it, and tied it in to the MainView, and then added the MainViewController and tied it to the File Owner and view.

When I run this, I get an 'Unrecognized Selector" error thrown on the initWithRootViewController line.

Can anyone see any problem with the code, or suggest a better way to add a navigation controller to a sub view?

Comment: Your code formatting is unusual, AppPadViewController.h -> AppPadViewController, *MainView -> *mainView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your two view controllers reversed. Try something like this:

```
self.MainView = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UINavigationController *mainNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:MainView];
```

Comment: This stops the error I was getting, but the view still doesnt have the navigation bar when I load the app. Is there another step I'm missing to make this appear? I have set the navigationItem.title of MainView in the main view controllers viewDidLoad function.

Comment: You should be adding the `UINavigationController`'s view to your window, not the `MainViewController`'s view.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if its entirely the 'correct' way of doing it, but I ended up creating a subview on the main page that I tied to a view in IB, and then added the UINavigationController to that view, so that I got the right size etc.